# how to remove file name from VIM dictionary menu?

Tags: vim

I've installed pydiction dictionary in vim so that I'd be able to get a list of python commands when I press tab after partially typed command. Everything is working fine, except every time the menu shows up, there is a file name besides the each command in the list. How do I remove that filename from the menu?

plz, take a look at the picture: http://www.uzbozor.com/uploads/vim.png
(copy and paste the link if clicking doesn't work)

Thanks

Comment: Your picture doesn't work - I get 403 Forbidden.

Comment: I realise this is an old post, but did you ever solve this problem?  I'm having the same problem trying to remove the dictionary name from the popup menu.

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution. Let me know if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't managed to solve this very elegantly, but there's a workaround by writing a custom completion function that simply greps the dictionary file for matches:

```
function! MyCompleteFunction( findstart, base )
  if a:findstart
    let line = getline('.')
    let start = col('.') - 1
    while start > 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '[A-Za-z_]'
        let start -= 1
    endwhile
    return start
  else
    silent call DictGrep( a:base, 'path\to\dictionary\file' )
    let matches = []
    for thismatch in getqflist()
        call add(matches, thismatch.text)
    endfor
    return matches
  endif
endfunction
```

Note that I have defined a function DictGrep() that actually performs the vimgrep. This is so I can call it silently and not be troubled by error messages:

```
function! DictGrep( leader, file )
    try
        exe "vimgrep /^" . a:leader . ".*/j " . a:file
    catch /.*/
        echo "no matches"
    endtry
endfunction
```

Then simply define set the completefunc:

```
setlocal completefunc=MyCompleteFunction()
```

and then use  for insert-mode completion (which could be mapped to replace your current dictionary completion binding).

The vimgrep could be quite a slow operation, but I haven't noticed any problems unless there are hundreds of matches in the dictionary file.

Hope this helps.