# Hide dictionary path in autocomplete popup menu

Tags: vim

I have been using insert mode auto-completion for some time now in vim, and I am very pleased with the results. However, I find it annoying (and unnecessary) that the popup menu contains the full path of the dictionary being used.

Is there a way to hide the dictionary path from the menu, or at least modify it in some way?

Comment: Help documentation on the autocomplete popup menu can be found with `:help complete`, with working example on how to make your own custom popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a workaround by defining my own 'completefunc' which gets its values from the specified dictionary file. But if there are any better solutions, please let me know!

My code for this solution is in [this question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830221/how-to-remove-file-name-from-vim-dictionary-menu).